# TypeError: done is not a function and TypeError: assert not a function

Tags: mongodb, authentication, express, passport.js

I am doing a mean stack app, and right now I am working on registering and sign in authentication. But I am having two errors! 
If I have"passReqToCallback: true" it gives me "done is not a function" but when I comment it out it is fine. But don't I need that?

After that it tells me that assert is not a function, then I tried to switch it with check, and it gave me that check isn't a function. 
I am so confused why It is giving these errors

```
var passport = require('passport');
var  User = require('../models/User');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var validator = require('express-validator');


passport.serializeUser(function(user , done ){
done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
User.findById(id,function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
});
});

passport.use('local.register', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'username',
emailField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback : true
}, function(req, username, email, password, done){
req.assert('username', 'Invalid username').notEmpty();
req.assert('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
req.assert('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({min: 4});

var errors = req.validationErrors();


if(errors){
var messages = [];
errors.forEach(function(error){
messages.push(error.msg);
});
return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
}
User.findOne({'username':username}, function(err, user){
if(err){
return done(err);
}
if(user){
return done(null, false, {message:'Username is already use'});
}

var newUser = new User();
newUser.username = username;
newUser.email = email;
newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
newUser.save(function(err, result) {
if (err) {
return done(err);
}
return done(null , newUser);
});
});
}));
passport.use('local.sign-in', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'username',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, done){
req.assert('username', 'Invalid username').notEmpty();
req.assert('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty();
var errors = req.validationErrors();
if(errors){
var messages = [];
errors.forEach(function(error){
messages.push(error.msg);
});
return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
}
//find user
User.findOne({'username': username}, function(err, user){
if(err){
return done(err);
}

        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found.'});
        }
        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password.'}); 
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });

     }));
```

Comment: Why do you pass `emailField` to `LocalStrategy`?

Comment: https://github.com/cecdelr/nodejs-shopping-cart i am following this register and signing in auth.

Comment: Yeah, but the example doesn't have `emailField`, only `usernameField: 'email'`. https://github.com/cecdelr/nodejs-shopping-cart/blob/master/config/passport.js#L20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#available-options the only options are `usernameField` and `passwordField`, and the callback only accepts `username, password, done` as arguments if `passReqToCallback` is `false`, and `req, username, password, done` if it's `true`. The `email` parameter in the callback shouldn't be there.

To be able to use `req.assert`, you need to have access to the `request` object, so, you need to pass `passReqToCallback: true`.

It should be something like this:

```
passport.use('local.register', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, function(req, username, password, done) {
    req.assert ...
});
```

This should fix both of your problems.

Comment: okay it does fix it but for my app it uses username email and password. How do i had the email then? or the only options are those

Comment: Those are the only options, if you want to use the `email` field instead of the `username` change the `usernameField` value to `'email'`: `usernameField: 'email'`.

Comment: aww that sucks can't use email and create a username. But thank you sooo much :)

Comment: No problem :). One doubt:  Why do you want to check for username, email & password? It shouldn't be sufficient with username/password or email/password, since username and email should be unique?